# Do all u-blox ZED-F9T input pins have internal pull-up resistors?

Tags: pullup, gps, receiver, gnss

The [ZED-F9T datasheet](https://content.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/ZED-F9T-00B_DataSheet_UBX-18053713.pdf) says in section 5 Communications Interfaces:

> All the inputs have internal pull-up resistors in normal operation and can be left open if not used.

This statement on its own seems pretty clear, but the fact that it occurs in the Communications interfaces sections gives me some doubt. Does this statement apply to all input pins and not just communication interface pins?

Another hint can be found in the suggested antenna supervisor circuit in the [integration manual](https://content.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/ZED-F9T_IntegrationManual_UBX-21040375.pdf):

[image]

The 74LVC3G07 is an open-drain buffer, and since I don't see any other pull-up resistors in the schematic, presumably the corresponding inputs (which are not part of the communications interface) have them.

So, am I right in thinking these are indeed present on all inputs?

Comment: you could do tests